# create multiple background worker in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, background

i am writing a program with background worker , i am creating it dynamically but how can i add doWork code inside  each background worker in vb.net

```
For NumWorkers As Integer = 0 To 3
  NumWorkers = NumWorkers + 1
  ReDim Workers(NumWorkers)
  Workers(NumWorkers) = New BackgroundWorker
  Workers(NumWorkers).WorkerReportsProgress = True
  Workers(NumWorkers).WorkerSupportsCancellation = True
  AddHandler Workers(NumWorkers).DoWork, AddressOf WorkerDoWork
  Workers(NumWorkers).RunWorkerAsync()
Next
 Private Sub WorkerDoWork(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs)
 ' for first
 End SUb

  Private Sub WorkerDoWork(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs)
 ' for 2nd
 End SUb

  Private Sub WorkerDoWork(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs)
 ' for 3rd
 End SUb

  Private Sub WorkerDoWork(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs)
 ' for 4th
 End SUb
```

i am confussing about last 3 workerDork() . how can i add the codes in it ??

Comment: the workers need to do 4 different jobs? then you cant do it in a loop

Comment: yes the workers need to do 4 different jobs .

Comment: `For NumWorkers As Integer = 0 To 3 [newline]
  NumWorkers = NumWorkers + 1` this is definitely wrong

Answer (score 2):

```
you Need to add handler and with  different address of each Background worker  
so you have to create each worker dynamically add different address for them .
```

Answer (score 2):

here an example of what you're trying to accomplish

```
Imports System.ComponentModel

Module Module1

  Sub Main()

    StartSomeThread(
      AddressOf Worker1DoWork,
      AddressOf Worker2DoWork,
      AddressOf Worker3DoWork,
      AddressOf Worker4DoWork)

  End Sub

  Private Sub Worker1DoWork(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As DoWorkEventArgs)

  End Sub
  Private Sub Worker2DoWork(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As DoWorkEventArgs)

  End Sub
  Private Sub Worker3DoWork(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As DoWorkEventArgs)

  End Sub
  Private Sub Worker4DoWork(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As DoWorkEventArgs)

  End Sub

  Private workers As New List(Of BackgroundWorker)

  Public Sub StartSomeThread(ParamArray jobs As Action(Of Object, DoWorkEventArgs)())

    For Each job In jobs

      Dim worker = New BackgroundWorker
      worker.WorkerReportsProgress = True
      worker.WorkerSupportsCancellation = True
      AddHandler worker.DoWork, AddressOf job.Invoke

      workers.Add(worker)

      worker.RunWorkerAsync()

    Next

  End Sub

End Module
```